# IntelliJ IDEA crash on startup (NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native)

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-10

Okay so I am using Windows 10, I am having issues starting up intelliJ IDEA as every time I run it, it throws the following error and crashes,

> Internal error. Please refer to
> https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors
>
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException: Cannot start app
> at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$start$15(StartupUtil.java:265)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:990)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:974)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1773)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1760)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> com.sun.jna.Native
> at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg$HKEYByReference.(WinReg.java:52)
> at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg$HKEYByReference.(WinReg.java:48)
> at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue(Advapi32Util.java:736)
> at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue(Advapi32Util.java:717)
> at com.intellij.openapi.util.WinBuildVersionKt.getWinBuildNumberInternal(WinBuildVersion.kt:14)
> at com.intellij.openapi.util.WinBuildVersionKt.access$getWinBuildNumberInternal(WinBuildVersion.kt:1)
> at com.intellij.openapi.util.WinBuildVersionKt$getWinBuildNumber$1.invoke(WinBuildVersion.kt:33)
> at com.intellij.openapi.util.WinBuildVersionKt$getWinBuildNumber$1.invoke(WinBuildVersion.kt)
> at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
> at com.intellij.openapi.util.WinBuildVersionKt.getWinBuildNumber(WinBuildVersion.kt:33)
> at com.intellij.openapi.util.SystemInfo.getWinBuildNumber(SystemInfo.java:123)
> at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.customFrameDecorations.header.CustomHeader$CustomFrameTopBorder.calculateAffectsBorders(CustomHeader.kt:276)
> at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.customFrameDecorations.header.CustomHeader$CustomFrameTopBorder.addNotify(CustomHeader.kt:346)
> at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.customFrameDecorations.header.CustomHeader.addNotify(CustomHeader.kt:158)
> at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.customFrameDecorations.header.DialogHeader.addNotify(DialogHeader.kt:59)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4847)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4847)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4847)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(JRootPane.java:729)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:797)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.addNotify(Dialog.java:770)
> at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.addNotify(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:641)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.pack(Window.java:835)
> at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.pack(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:311)
> at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.pack(DialogWrapper.java:1432)
> at com.intellij.ide.gdpr.AgreementUi.pack(AgreementUi.kt:254)
> at com.intellij.ide.gdpr.Agreements.showEndUserAndDataSharingAgreements(Agreements.kt:19)
> at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$showEuaIfNeeded$25(StartupUtil.java:607)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:779)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:730)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:749)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:393)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
>
> ----- Your JRE: 17.0.3+7-b469.32 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.) C:\Program Files\Jetbrains\IntelliJ IDEA\jbr

Has anyone encountered something like this? I've never seen this issue before so completely clueless, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

When running the IntelliJ IDEA, a dll
`C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.2\tmp\jnaxxxx.dll` is extracted in IDEA's temp dir and executed.

In Windows, some security tools can restrict the folders where binaries (e.g. dll, ...) can be executed.

If you have security tools installed, ensure that [all IDE](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs), project, and IDE installation directories are added to the exclusions list.